# System.AsyncException You have exceeded the limit of 100 Jobs in the flex queue

Tags: apex, apex-flex-queue, jobs

While creating a Lead or while Editing an Account most of the users
are getting the below Error message :
[image]

Also,

As mentioned in the below links to contact Salesforce Support , but we couldnt contact them as since we have a standard support contract and they support Apex issues only on premium support contract:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213851&type=1
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008g2NQAQ
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008YgIAAU

Also I tried to implement the workaround suggested as in the below link but that gave me errors related to other classes so was unable to deploy it :

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000MTVgQAO

So as a Temporary fix though its not recommended to Abort the Holding jobs we are aborting it for the users to carry on with their activities.

Hence if anyone have had the same situation kindly help me...!
Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Can you share the code on how you are posting the job

Comment: did you actually indented to queue 100 jobs or it is just a recursion issue which is causing to queue more than 100 jobs?

Comment: Edit your question and add the code

Comment: @RatanPaul - We didnt intend to do this.We suddenly landed upto this.

Comment: @SantanuBoral : The Lead Trigger is calling the below Lead Handler Class :

Comment: @SushmaRamakrishnan Just check in debug like if your code is going into loop or not. And also check if any queuable class is in queue multiple times or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue got solved by raising a case with Salesforce Support & getting the queued jobs/tokens deleted by them.